# ' mashape api key missing', even when I use my key

Tags: ruby, mashape

I am trying to build a Ruby app using the Yoda Speak api. I keep getting

```
{\"message\":\"Missing Mashape application key. Go to http:\\/\\/docs.mashape.com\\/api-keys to learn how to get your API application key.\"}
```

in my response even when I include my api key.  My code is:

```
url = "https://yoda.p.mashape.com/yoda?sentence=You+will+learn+how+to+speak+like+me+someday.++Oh+wait."
yoda_tweet = Unirest.get(url, headers:{
"X-Mashape-key" =>  ENV['MASHAPE_KEY],
"Accept" => "text/plain"
})
```

I've tried putting the key in directly without the ENV but it still says key missing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: HTTP headers are supposed to be case insensitive, but just in case, can you try again with `X-Mashape-Key`?

Comment: Make sure you're using the unirest gem v1.1.2

Comment: ENV['MASHAPE_KEY] - Typo